# Use a for loop to set values in an array

Tags: ios, json, for-loop

I have a `UITableViewController` that uses an array with values for every entry in the rows. 
I want to set the values of that array by iterating over values read from a JSON file.

This is the new method I have created to read that data into an array and return it to my view controller. I don't know where to return the array, or how to really set it.

```
+(NSArray *)setDataToJson{
NSDictionary *infomation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString:@"Test.json"];
NSArray *test = [infomation valueForKey:@"Animals"];
for (int i = 0; i < test.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *info = [test objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[Animal animalObj:[info valueForKey:@"AnimalName"] 
location:[info valueForKey:@"ScientificName"] description:[info valueForKey:@"FirstDesc"] image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cat.png"]], nil];
        return array;
```

I know that my animalObj function worked when the data was local strings(@"Cat") and my `dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONString` works because I have tested, but I haven't used this function to set data to an array, only to UILabels, so this is where I am confused, on how to set this data into an array. But still use the For loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an instance of
[`NSMutableArray`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html),
which will let you incrementally add elements to the array as you
iterate with the for-loop:

```
...
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < test.count; i++) { 
    NSDictionary *info = [test objectAtIndex:i]; 
    Animal *animal = [Animal animalObj:[info valueForKey:@"AnimalName"]  
                              location:[info valueForKey:@"ScientificName"] 
                           description:[info valueForKey:@"FirstDesc"] 
                                 image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cat.png"]];
    [array addObject:animal];
}
return array;
```

Because `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, there's no need change the return type of your method.

Comment: When I do `(lldb) po test
(NSArray *) $26 = 0x06fb5000 [no Objective-C description available]` but when I did that in my other class, the test one for this function, it saids `po test
(NSArray *) $27 = 0x06a4e930 <ViewController: 0x6a4e930>` Why does it not work on my NSObject class of Animal? any suggestions?

Comment: Implement a [`description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) method for your class.

Comment: I did that and I still get `(lldb) po test
(NSArray *) $5 = 0x07995b40 <__NSArrayI 0x7995b40>(
<null>,
<null>
)`